# How to stop server process during a post on client side?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, client-server

I develop an `ASP .NET/C# MVC4 application` where users can click on a button (post) a let the server running his algorithm`.

The process can be long (several minutes) and if the user closes his window/stop the loading the server keeps running and, in my application, insert data in the DB.

I asked myself how it is possible to `stop this server process` with the application ? I mean, `if the user realizes he doesn't want to run this process anymore and he likes to stop insertion in database`, how can he do that ?

Comment: You can send Ajax Request to Server when user Unload the Browser on OnUnload() Event of the Window. Or Whenever user clicks on the Stop Button. But, you should manage your server Script which running to Acknowledge that Request that If there is Something value like STOP somewhere then stop running the Process. Hope you got what i want to say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create static class/singleton in service layer with methods which will run and stop  your `long process`. In controller you can make some actions which will manage this singleton by user requests.